# Telegram Bot - ApiRequestException: Not Found on C#

Tags: c#, telegram

I'm trying to write a bot for Telegram on C#.
I tried some basic syntax, the program is primitive:

```
    using Telegram.Bot;
    var botClient = new TelegramBotClient("{YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE}");
    var me = await botClient.GetMeAsync();
Console.WriteLine($"Hello, World! I am user {me.Id} and my name is {me.FirstName}.");
```

Then when I'm running the code the Debug Console outputs the following:

> Unhandled exception. Telegram.Bot.Exceptions.ApiRequestException: Not
> Found    at
> Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClient.MakeRequestAsync[TResponse](IRequest`1
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClientExtensions.GetMeAsync(ITelegramBotClient
> botClient, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Program.$(String[] args) in
> D:\Projects\My_Bot\My_Bot\Program.cs:line 5    at
> Program.(String[] args)

While the error list is empty.
How can I get rid of this exception and get a proper output?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you replace `{YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE}` with your token? Until you do you'll receive the `Not Found` exception. If you did, then you may want to validate that you have a valid token.

If you haven't got a token, you can get one by messaging the [BotFather](https://t.me/botfather) on telegram. It's a bot designed by Telegram to help you through the process.

Here's the documentation from Telegram on setting up everything. https://core.telegram.org/bots

**EDIT**

To use BotFather:

1. Send [BotFather](https://t.me/botfather) `/newbot`.
2. Enter a bot name, this can be anything you want for display purposes.
3. Enter a bot username, this has to be unique and must end in `_bot`.
4. Copy the token from the message, and paste it into the code.

Here's a sample output you will receive after successfully setting up the bot: (removed sensitive info)

> Done! Congratulations on your new bot. You will find it at t.me/. You
> can now add a description, about section and profile picture for your
> bot, see /help for a list of commands. By the way, when you've
> finished creating your cool bot, ping our Bot Support if you want a
> better username for it. Just make sure the bot is fully operational
> before you do this.
>
> Use this token to access the HTTP API: **{YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}** Keep your
> token secure and store it safely, it can be used by anyone to control
> your bot.

For a description of the Bot API, see this page: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api

Comment: Yes, I've replaced the placeholder with a token from BF. Didn't show it here in case of security.

Comment: k, then sounds like the token might be wrong. When I get a token from telegram and paste it directly into the the code you provided, everything works as expected. I updated the answer to explain how to use the BotFather in case you need it. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I'll recheck the Bot's documentation and revise my code.

Answer (score 0):

I now that it is too late but,guys, write NOT "{12312312411313123123}" BUT
"12312312312312313". It worked!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).